# Using regex in python on multiple text files to parse and collect data to add to excel

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am extremely new to python and I need to work with regex.

I have multiple .txt files in a directory that I need to parse. Each of these .txt file has multiple occurrence of the word "instruction" in it. I need the grab the number that follows the word "instruction" and add it to a list that I will display in excel. This is done in a way that I have a column of "Instruction" with all the instruction numbers and I have a row of all the .txt file names. I need to end up putting a yes or no in front of the instruction number if it is present in a particular .txt file.

I want to know how to grab the number that follows the word "instruction" and add it to a list (maybe). And use this list later to formulate an excel file. What is the way to write this regex instruction?

This is my code so far

```
import csv  
import re    
import glob 
import os 

inst_num = []

os.chdir (r"C:\Users\10002\Desktop\work\scripts")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open (file, 'r') as f: 
        for line in f:
            inst = re.compile ('instruction:(\d+)',line)
            if inst.search(line) is not None:
                inst_num = inst.search(line).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `compile` does not take the text string that is to be searched as a second argument (the optional second argument are flags to be used, e.g. `re.IGNORECASE`). Second, the call to `compile` should be taken out of the loop or else you are defeating the purpose of pre-compiling the regular expression. Third, you are asking multiple questions, which is generally frowned upon. I will show you how to create a list of numbers. If you have a separate question on how to create a CSV file from that, post a separate question.

```
import csv  
import re    
import glob 
import os 

inst_num = []
inst = re.compile('instruction:(\d+)') # compiled regex

os.chdir (r"C:\Users\10002\Desktop\work\scripts")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open (file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            match = inst.search(line) # do the search once
            if match:
                inst_num.append(match.group(1)) # add to list
```